# SQL command to sum up data group by date

Tags: sql

I have a database that contain:

```
+----+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| id | date                |          pay|        usr_type |
+----+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
|  1 | 2016-10-17          |          500|             boss|
|  2 | 2016-10-17          |          200|             boss|
|  3 | 2016-10-24          |          300|             user|
|  4 | 2016-10-24          |          100|             user|
+----+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

I want the results something like this:

```
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| date                |         user|             boss|
+----+---------------------+--------+-----------------+
| 2016-10-17          |            0|              700|
| 2016-10-24          |          400|                0|
+----+---------------------+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select date, 
    sum(case when usr_type = 'user' then pay else 0 end) user,
    sum(case when usr_type = 'boss' then pay else 0 end) boss
from yourtable
group by date
```

Comment: Can I put two condition in WHEN clause?

Comment: @windc Sure, >>  when usr_type = 'user'  and usr_active=1 then ... << for example